# Solver Doesn't works for the second time when I run it

Tags: vba, excel, solver

The below code works perfectly the first time when I run it,

But when I run it again the second or third time then

it gives me a msgbox which is from solver telling it found the solution then when I click select `OK`

it just exits out of the Sub. Don't understand why.

Also I wanted to know how to give `OK` command to the prompt from Solver dialog box via vba ? Or just simply avoid it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MinimizeCost()

Dim wm, ws, wr As Worksheet
Dim i, j, FinalRow As Long
Dim char As Variant
Dim ScnCap, ScnDem As Range

Set wm = Sheets("Model")
Set ws = Sheets("Scenarios")
Set wr = Sheets("Results")

For i = 1 To 5

With ws
 j = i + 1
  Set ScnCap = .Range(.Cells(5, j), .Cells(7, j))
End With

wm.Range("Capacities") = ScnCap.Value

With ws
 j = i + 1
  Set ScnDem = .Range(.Cells(10, j), .Cells(13, j))
End With

ScnDem.Copy
wm.Range("Demands").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Call Solveit

FinalRow = wr.Range("A9000").End(xlUp).Row
FinalRow = FinalRow + 1

wr.Range("A" & FinalRow + 1) = "Scenario" & " " & i
wr.Range("A" & FinalRow + 2) = "Shipments"
wr.Range("F" & FinalRow + 2) = "Total Cost"

wm.Range("TotalCost").Copy
wr.Range("F" & FinalRow + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wm.Range("Shipped").Copy
wr.Range("A" & FinalRow + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

SendKeys ("{ESC}")
wm.Range("A1").Select
Next i 
End Sub

Sub Solveit()

Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Sheets("Model")
wk.Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$20", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$13:$F$15", _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$20", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$13:$F$15", _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverSolve

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On the [microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821349.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it explains everything about the sovler in Excel-VBA. Replacing your `SolverSolve` line by

```
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
```

should avoid the msgBox to pop up at the end.

On the issue regarding the wrong second-run solution, I suggests to add `SolverReset`at the begining of `Solveit()`function. As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821349.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it will cause cell selection to reset, which might be a problem when running a solver multiple times.
And also, you shouldn't have 2 `SolverOk` set within a solver, especially if they have the exact same properties...
In the end, something like this should do the job :

```
Sub Solveit()

Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Sheets("Model")
wk.Select

SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$B$20", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, _
    ByChange:="$C$13:$F$15", Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

End Sub
```

And by the way, be careful with statement like :

```
wm.Range("Shipped").Copy
wr.Range("A" & FinalRow + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

VBA handles copy/paste pretty badly, if you just want to copy a cell's value to another (also works with Range given they have the same dimension), just write :

```
wr.Range("A" & FinalRow + 3).value = wn.Range("Shipped").value
```

This will make your code more clear to debug and faster to run.